# SQL using #table/ Temp table inside a table valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, temp-tables

I need to have a function to get all the week numbers in a given date range.
I have to seperate this from my stored procedure since it has a lengthy process.

But when I use #tables in side the function it gives following error

> Msg 2772, Level 16, State 1, Procedure WeekNumbersWithinRange, Line 19
>   Cannot access temporary tables from within a function.

And here is my function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION WeekNumbersWithinRange
(   
    @FromDate DATETIME,
    @ToDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb..#WeeksofRange', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #WeeksofRange
    END

    CREATE TABLE #WeeksofRange (WeekNo  INT);

    -- Get all week numbers for the given delivery date range
    IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb..#Calendar', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Calendar
    END

    CREATE TABLE #Calendar
    (
         CalendarDate DATE PRIMARY KEY,
         IsWeekend BIT, 
         YearNo SMALLINT, 
         QuarterNo TINYINT, 
         MonthNo TINYINT,
         DayOfYearNo SMALLINT, 
         DayNo TINYINT, 
         WeekNo TINYINT, 
         WeekDayNo TINYINT
    )

    DECLARE @beginDate DATE, @endDate DATE

    SELECT 
        @beginDate = @FromDate, @endDate = @ToDate

    WHILE @beginDate <= @endDate 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Calendar (CalendarDate, IsWeekend, YearNo, QuarterNo, MonthNo, DayOfYearNo, DayNo, WeekNo, WeekDayNo)
            SELECT
                @beginDate As CalendarDate,
                (CASE WHEN DATEPART(Weekday, @beginDate) IN (7, 1) 
                         THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                 END) AS IsWeekend,
                DATEPART(Year, @beginDate) AS YearNo,
                DATEPART(QUARTER, @beginDate) AS QuarterNo,
                DATEPART(MONTH, @beginDate) AS MonthNo,
                DATEPART(DayOfYear, @beginDate) AS DayOfYearNo, 
                DATEPART(Day, @beginDate) AS DayNo,
                DATEPART(Week, @beginDate) AS WeekNo,
                DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @beginDate) AS WeekDayNo
                --,(Case When @beginDate < '02/03/2011' Then 0 Else DATEPART(Week,  @beginDate) - 5 End) As mySpecificWeekNo

        SET @beginDate = DATEADD(Day, 1, @beginDate)
    END

    INSERT INTO #WeeksofRange
        SELECT DISTINCT WeekNo 
        FROM #Calendar;

    -- End of Select all week numbers in the range

    SELECT * FROM #WeeksofRange
GO
```

Is there any other way to do this? Or do I need to write this logic inside my stored procedure?

Comment: Instead of using a Temp table, use a table variable, that should solve your problem.

Comment: Why not create a permanent calendar table and just query it? a centuries worth of rows is still a *small* table, by most measures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a Temp table in UDF because

> the object can't be created inside UDF.

Instead of using a Temp table, use a table variable, that should solve your problem

```
CREATE FUNCTION WeekNumbersWithinRange
(   
    @FromDate DATETIME,
    @ToDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @WeeksofRange TABLE 
(
WeekNo  INT
)

-- Get all week numbers for the given delivery date range

declare @Calendar table
(CalendarDate Date Primary key, IsWeekend Bit, YearNo SmallInt, QuarterNo TinyInt, MonthNo TinyInt, DayOfYearNo SmallInt, DayNo TinyInt, WeekNo TinyInt, WeekDayNo TinyInt )

Declare @beginDate Date, @endDate Date


Select @beginDate = @FromDate , @endDate = @ToDate


While @beginDate <= @endDate 
Begin
 Insert Into @Calendar (CalendarDate, IsWeekend, YearNo, QuarterNo, MonthNo, DayOfYearNo, DayNo, WeekNo, WeekDayNo)

 Select
  @beginDate As CalendarDate  
  ,(Case When DATEPART(Weekday, @beginDate) In (7, 1) Then 1 Else 0 End) As IsWeekend 
  ,DATEPART(Year, @beginDate) As YearNo 
  ,DATEPART(QUARTER, @beginDate) As QuarterNo 
  ,DATEPART(MONTH, @beginDate) As MonthNo 
  ,DATEPART(DayOfYear, @beginDate) As DayOfYearNo 
  ,DATEPART(Day, @beginDate) As DayNo   
  ,DATEPART(Week, @beginDate) As WeekNo
  ,DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @beginDate) As WeekDayNo 
  --,(Case When @beginDate < '02/03/2011' Then 0 Else DATEPART(Week, @beginDate) - 5 End) As mySpecificWeekNo
 Set @beginDate = DateAdd(Day, 1, @beginDate)
End

INSERT INTO @calendar
SELECT DISTINCT WeekNo FROM @Calendar;

-- End of Select all week numbers in the range


SELECT * FROM @WeeksofRange

GO
```

Comment: I Have this problem. Basically I want to alter the table variable by adding dynamic columns, which will not allow me until I have a temp table. How can I solve a problem like this ?

Comment: @user123456 you cannot do DDL commands on tables variable. try with CTE

Answer (score 0):

I'd normally choose to make the `Calendar` table permanent and populate it with, say, a centuries worth of rows. And then just query it.

But, if you *have* to have this function, you can write it to use a CTE and avoid any explicit state/iteration management:

```
CREATE FUNCTION WeekNumbersWithinRange
(   
    @FromDate DATETIME,
    @ToDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
    return (With Weeks as (
        select DATEPART(week,@FromDate) as Week,@FromDate as dt
        union all
        select DATEPART(week,ndt),ndt
        from Weeks
            cross apply (select DATEADD(day,7,dt) as ndt) t
        where
            ndt < @ToDate
    )
    select Week from Weeks
    union
    select DATEPART(week,@ToDate)
    )
```

I've made the simplifying assumption that week numbers only change every 7 days so we don't need to generate a row for every day inside the CTE. Also, I use the final `UNION` to make sure that the final week is included. It *could* be skipped since I'm working in 7 day increments, so we could jump our value straight from a previous week to a value greater than `@ToDate`.

Depending on the ranges you're working with, you may have to apply the `MAXRECURSION` option to the query to allow the CTE to work fully.